# Weird render issue, can't get rid of topology like line shadows (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been recently encountering weird shadows on certain parts of my model, for example, on the character's leg. It only occurs on certain parts of the model which makes me confused.

[image: Render]

It seems to be more noticeable the more I increase the normal map's strength and disappears when I turn it off so it could be linked to my normal map but I don't understand what could be wrong with my normal map.

[image: Normal]

the red circle is where the leg's uvs are at

Edit : It seems that the issue doesn't show up when I rendered my model with Eevee. Still can't find a solution for Cycles

Edit 2 : Here's a gif of my topology https://i.imgur.com/yFAVntT.gif

Comment: In some regions, the normal map has very harsh edges. Try to smooth it and see if it changes anything

Comment: I tried smoothing it, sadly it did't change anything at all

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Do you have the shading on the object set to Flat or Smooth? It looks to me like the shading on the pants is set to Flat, which can cause the edges to show up.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! It is on Shade Smooth, and if it matters, I also have Auto Smooth checked on the object data

Comment: Here is a gif to show the topology if that help clears some stuff up as well 
https://i.imgur.com/yFAVntT.gif